# Error in solve.default(oout$hessian) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0

Tags: r, optimization, statistics, mathematical-optimization, log-likelihood

I am using the maximum likelihood method to estimate a set of parameters. Now I am going to use  `mle` function from the `stats4` package in R to make a profile likelihood for one of the parameters. To do that, I need to fix one of the parameters when I call the `mle` function. Here is the code:

```
fr <- function(x1, x2, x3) {   
  100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2 + x3
}

out <- mle(fr,start = list(x1=1, x2=2, x3=3), method="Nelder-Mead",
           control=list(trace=4), fixed = list(x2=1))
```

and I get this error:

> Error in solve.default(oout$hessian) :
> Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0

If I do not use the `fixed` option, then I do not have this error, but the result is not a profile likelihood. Can you please let me know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: We really need a [mcve] in order to be able to tackle this one ...

Comment: @BenBolker I edited my post and provide an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** I'm not sure your objective function makes sense, my guess is that you have a typo. (Furthermore, if your objective function is working with `mle`, you don't need to set `fixed` explicitly: the `profile` method will automatically compute likelihood profiles for you ...)

---

Let's start with the full model, and let's use `optim()` rather than `stats4::mle()` (I know you want to get back to `mle` so that you can do likelihood profiling, but it's a little bit easier to debug `optim()` problems since there is one less layer of code to dig through.)

Since `optim()` wants an objective function that takes a vector rather than a list of arguments, write a wrapper (we could also use `do.call(fr, as.list(p))`):

```r
fr0 <- function(p) {
  fr(x1=p[1], x2=p[2], x3=p[3])
}
opt1 <- optim(fn=fr0, par=c(1,2,3), method="Nelder-Mead")
```

Results:

```r
$par
[1]    28.51486   812.09978 -7095.39630

$value
[1] -6238.881

$counts
function gradient 
     502       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1
```

Note that the value of `x[3]` is strongly negative, as is the objective function value, and **the convergence code is non-zero**: in particular means (from `?optim`):

> ‘1’ indicates that the iteration limit ‘maxit’ had been reached.

If we set `control=list(maxit=2000)` and try again `x3` and the objective function get even smaller and the convergence code is still 1!

Then we *look more carefully at the objective function* and notice that it goes to `-Inf` as `x3` → `Inf`, so we'll never reach the answer. (Presumably at some point we'll get to a floating-point problem, but 10 million iterations only gets us as a far as `-1e17` ...)

If I change `x3` to `x3^2` in your function everything seems to work OK ... maybe that's what you intended ... ???